# Determining uniqueness of solution of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have an IVP:

$$x'=\frac{2x\sqrt\ln(x)}{t}$$
$$x(t_0)=1$$
and $t_0 >0$ , $x>1$

The question is:

Does this IVP have a unique solution for any value of $t_0$ ?

---

I found the general solution which is $x(t)=e^{(ln(t) +C)^2}$ but ODEs are quite a new thing to me and the existance and uniqueness issues are still a bit unclear for me, so I would appreciate any explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual Picard–Lindelöf Existence and Uniqueness Theorem applies when the right side of your equation and its partial derivative with respect to $x$ are continuous in a neighbourhood of the initial condition $(x_0, t_0)$.  This is the case for your initial condition
since $x_0 > 1$ (so there is no problem with the square root of the logarithm) and $t_0 > 0$ (so there is no problem with division by $t$).  So yes, there is a unique solution satisfying the initial condition defined in some neighbourhood of $t_0$.  It may stop existing or stop being unique if it runs off to $\pm \infty$ or leaves the region $(x > 1, t>0$).

EDITED AGAIN: For example, consider the case $t_0 = 1$, $x_0 = e$.  The solution you found is $x = e^{(1 + \ln t)^2}$.  However, (assuming as usual we take the positive square root) that is only a solution when $1 + \ln t \ge 0$, i.e. $t \ge 1/e$.  On the other hand the constant $x=1$ is a solution.  Thus the actual (unique) solution with this initial point is
$$ x(t) = \cases{1 & if $0 < t \le 1/e$\cr
              e^{(1+\ln t)^2} & if $t \ge 1/e$\cr}$$

Comment: So am I correct that if we leave the assumption $x_0>1$ and set the initial value to $x(t_0)=1$ than we can have a constant solution $x=1$ and therefore there would be no uniqueness, right?

Comment: Yes, with initial condition $x(t_0) = 1$ we don't have uniqueness because we have $x=1$ and also solutions of the form $$x(t) = \cases{1 & if $0 < t \le t_1$\cr e^{(\ln(t) - \ln(t_1))^2} & if $t \ge t_1$}$$ for any $t_1 > t_0$.